# R combining date columns

Tags: r, date

I have a data.frame like below.

```
toolid          startdate       enddate         stage
abc                 1-Jan-13    5-Jan-13    production
abc                 6-Jan-13    10-Jan-13   down
xyz                 3-Jan-13    8-Jan-13    production
xyz                 9-Jan-13    15-Jan-13   down
```

I want to transform the data.frame into the format below. I am trying to combine columns `'startdate'` and `'enddate'` from above data.frame into a single column called `'date'` below. Original data that I have has over a few thousand rows across many `toolids` and many stages. I already found a way to do this using SQL, but would prefer a R solution. I have started by melting the data as shown in the code below.

```
toolid  date            stage
abc     1-Jan-13    production
abc     2-Jan-13    production
abc     3-Jan-13    production
abc     4-Jan-13    production
abc     5-Jan-13    production
abc     6-Jan-13    down
abc     7-Jan-13    down
abc     8-Jan-13    down
abc     9-Jan-13    down
abc     10-Jan-13   down
xyz     3-Jan-13    production
xyz     4-Jan-13    production
xyz     5-Jan-13    production
xyz     6-Jan-13    production
xyz     7-Jan-13    production
xyz     8-Jan-13    production
xyz     9-Jan-13    down
xyz     10-Jan-13   down
xyz     11-Jan-13   down
xyz     12-Jan-13   down
xyz     13-Jan-13   down
xyz     14-Jan-13   down
xyz     15-Jan-13   down
```

R code

```
startdate=c('1-Jan-13','6-Jan-13','3-Jan-13','9-Jan-13')
enddate=c('5-Jan-13',    '10-Jan-13',   '8-Jan-13', '15-Jan-13')
toolid=c('abc',     'abc',  'xyz',  'xyz')
stage=c('production',    'down',    'production',   'down')
data=data.frame(toolid,startdate,enddate,stage)
require(reshape2)
newdata=melt(data,id.vars=c('toolid','stage'))
```

update: coping code from @[Ananda Mahto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1270695/ananda-mahto) answer below and adding few lines of code to give a pivot table kind of output

```
## Convert "startdate" and "enddate" to date objects
data$startdate <- as.Date(data$startdate, format="%d-%b-%y")
data$enddate <- as.Date(data$enddate, format="%d-%b-%y")


## Use `seq` to create the date sequence, and manually recreate
##   your dataframe. `do.call(rbind, ...) to put it back together
ddd=do.call(rbind, lapply(sequence(nrow(data)), function(x) {
  data.frame(toolid = data$toolid[x], 
             date = seq(data$startdate[x], data$enddate[x], by = 1),
             stage = data$stage[x])
}))

ddd


   toolid       date      stage
1     abc 2013-01-01 production
2     abc 2013-01-02 production
3     abc 2013-01-03 production
4     abc 2013-01-04 production
5     abc 2013-01-05 production
6     abc 2013-01-06       down
7     abc 2013-01-07       down
8     abc 2013-01-08       down
9     abc 2013-01-09       down
10    abc 2013-01-10       down
11    xyz 2013-01-03 production
12    xyz 2013-01-04 production
13    xyz 2013-01-05 production
14    xyz 2013-01-06 production
15    xyz 2013-01-07 production
16    xyz 2013-01-08 production
17    xyz 2013-01-09       down
18    xyz 2013-01-10       down
19    xyz 2013-01-11       down
20    xyz 2013-01-12       down
21    xyz 2013-01-13       down
22    xyz 2013-01-14       down
23    xyz 2013-01-15       down

ddd1=dcast(ddd,date~stage)


ddd1
         date down production
1  2013-01-01    0          1
2  2013-01-02    0          1
3  2013-01-03    0          2
4  2013-01-04    0          2
5  2013-01-05    0          2
6  2013-01-06    1          1
7  2013-01-07    1          1
8  2013-01-08    1          1
9  2013-01-09    2          0
10 2013-01-10    2          0
11 2013-01-11    1          0
12 2013-01-12    1          0
13 2013-01-13    1          0
14 2013-01-14    1          0
15 2013-01-15    1          0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure there are more "correct" ways to do this, but this is what came to my mind quickly.

First, convert "startdate" and "enddate" to date objects

```
data$startdate <- as.Date(data$startdate, format="%d-%b-%y")
data$enddate <- as.Date(data$enddate, format="%d-%b-%y")
```

Then,  use `seq` to create the date sequence, and manually recreate your `data.frame`. Use `do.call(rbind, ...) to put it back together.

```
ddd <- do.call(rbind, lapply(sequence(nrow(data)), function(x) {
  data.frame(toolid = data$toolid[x], 
             date = seq(data$startdate[x], data$enddate[x], by = 1),
             stage = data$stage[x])
}))
ddd
#    toolid       date      stage
# 1     abc 2013-01-01 production
# 2     abc 2013-01-02 production
# 3     abc 2013-01-03 production
# 4     abc 2013-01-04 production
# 5     abc 2013-01-05 production
# 6     abc 2013-01-06       down
# 7     abc 2013-01-07       down
# 8     abc 2013-01-08       down
# 9     abc 2013-01-09       down
# 10    abc 2013-01-10       down
# 11    xyz 2013-01-03 production
# 12    xyz 2013-01-04 production
# 13    xyz 2013-01-05 production
# 14    xyz 2013-01-06 production
# 15    xyz 2013-01-07 production
# 16    xyz 2013-01-08 production
# 17    xyz 2013-01-09       down
# 18    xyz 2013-01-10       down
# 19    xyz 2013-01-11       down
# 20    xyz 2013-01-12       down
# 21    xyz 2013-01-13       down
# 22    xyz 2013-01-14       down
# 23    xyz 2013-01-15       down
```

Finally, looking at where you say you want to end up, you can stick to base R all the way and use `table`. I've put it in `as.data.frame.matrix()` because I've assumed you want a `data.frame` as the result:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(ddd[-1]))
#            down production
# 2013-01-01    0          1
# 2013-01-02    0          1
# 2013-01-03    0          2
# 2013-01-04    0          2
# 2013-01-05    0          2
# 2013-01-06    1          1
# 2013-01-07    1          1
# 2013-01-08    1          1
# 2013-01-09    2          0
# 2013-01-10    2          0
# 2013-01-11    1          0
# 2013-01-12    1          0
# 2013-01-13    1          0
# 2013-01-14    1          0
# 2013-01-15    1          0
```

Comment: +1 - for making me laugh: *this is what came to my mind quickly*. Yeah, I was just thinking that too. Awesome stuff.

Comment: @SimonO101, I'm sure some `zoo`/`xts` solution exists, but I might have to Google to find that....

Comment: i used @AnandaMahto code and pasted it in my original question. I have added a few more lines of code to get the final output that i was looking for. Let me know if there is any better way to get that similar output....when i type dcast command i get below message "Using stage as value column: use value.var to override.
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length" but still i get the output that i am looking for

Comment: @user2543622, those are just messages, not warnings or errors. Basically, `dcast` is telling you which data it used and how it used it. If the output is incorrect, then it tells you that you should specify `value.var = <somevariable>` and specify what aggregation function (eg, `sum`, `mean`) you want to use (where `length` is default).

Comment: @user2543622, But to answer your question if there are other ways to do this, of course there are. This is R ;) You can use `table`, for example, `table(ddd[-1])`, which will return a matrix of class "table". If you want the output as a `data.frame`, you can do `as.data.frame.matrix(table(ddd[-1]))`.